# Get angle of clicked position on arc svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

Let's say I have `svg`, drawn like this:

```
var myArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(width / 5)
    .outerRadius(width / 2);

myArc.startAngle(function(d, i) {
    return radians * i
});

myArc.endAngle(function(d, i) {
    return radians * (i + 1)
```

...and is later filled with some color, etc. It looks like this:

[image: svg circle]

Now, I want on `svg` click to get angle degree. Example: I want to get between ~ 310° and 50° when I click on red, 70° or so when I click on yellow etc.

How would I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I searched a lot and found out some equations for calculating center of circle coordinates, and after that I would find coordinates of clicked position to calculate angle based on those two. But I would like some simpler solution, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do some research, didn't find any simpler solution.
I am using the way you mentioned: get center of circle and clicked position, then calculate angle based on those two. I don't think this is too complex to use.

Note: because the circle is not really circle, so there are some numerical errors.

Hope this is useful.

```js
(function($){
  var center = {};
  
  var calculateAngle = function(x, y){
    var k = Math.abs(y) / Math.abs(x);
    var angle = Math.atan(k) * 180 / Math.PI;
    if(y * x > 0){
     angle = 90 - angle + (y < 0 ? 180 : 0);
    } else {
      angle = angle + (y < 0 ? 90 : 270);
    }
    
    return angle;
  }
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('#container');
    var $selector = $('#selector');
    var $result = $('#result');
    
    center = {
      x: $container.width() / 2,
      y: $container.height() / 2
    }    
    $selector.css({left:center.x, top:center.y});
    
    $container.on('click', function(e){
     var x = e.offsetX;
      var y = e.offsetY;
      $selector.css({left:x, top:y});
      var angle = calculateAngle(x - center.x, center.y - y);
      
      $result.text(angle);
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
#container{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  
}

#selector{
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <span id="selector"></span>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X8A7.png">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Result: </span>
  <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tinmar ^_^ Thank you for the feedback.